# (Mac) Calling a shell script from another shell script is giving an access error when running java

Tags: java, bash, shell, terminal

I am a front-end dev working on a project for a client. Our back-end team has provided me with several java scripts that must be run which provide data to the application. All of these scripts are run from the command line.

What we've been asked to do is to open several instances of Terminal (or several tabs is fine too) and run one script (which calls the java app) per terminal window.

Right now, doing that involves opening all the windows by hand, using "cd" commands to get to the correct folder(s), and then running the java command, all by hand. I'd like to automate this process.

First, I wrote a shell script (launch_language) to call the java file in the correct folder. **Running this command by itself works just fine, and runs the program as expected**:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar mercury/language-packs/language-connector/target/language-connector-1.12.7.jar
```

So far, so good.

Now, I want to write another script, which will open a new Terminal window, then load and run this working script. Okay, so:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Terminal.app launch_language
```

Running this script opens a new terminal window as expected, and launches the launch_language script. When that happens however, the Terminal gives me this error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile mercury/language-packs/language-connector/target/language-connector-1.12.7.jar
```

Any thoughts as to why calling the launch_language script this way is causing this error to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative path in your script - so it works only if you run it from specific directory.

Possible solutions:

1. add `cd /FULL_PATH_TO_DIR` before `java -jar` command
2. provide full path to jar (`/FULL_PATH_TO_DIR/mercury/language-packs/language-connector/target/language-connector-1.12.7.jar`)

Comment: Option #2 worked perfectly for me. I located my default folder in Finder, and then right-clicked on the breadcrumbs to copy the exact path from root. Boom. Worked. Thanks!